# I am trying to reproduce an image in LaTex (Texshop, scrbook). How do I get it?

Tags: floats, multicolumn, multirow, scrbook

I want to reproduce the below image. How do I get it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=17cm:24cm,11pt,DIV=12,BCOR=10mm,headinclude=true,pagesize=false,headings=small,table]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\providecommand{\\}{\\}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\ef{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
Past \hspace{0.5cm} \= \hspace{3cm} \= | 1. \textit{avidyā}, ignorance (blind camel)\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 2. \textit{saṃskāra}, latent dispositions (pot-maker)\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| \textit{upapattibhāva} \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 3. \textit{vijñāna}, rebirth-consciousness (ape)\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| or Receptive \\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| side of life\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 4. \textit{nāmarūpa}, name and form (ferryman)\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 5. \textit{ṣaḍāyatana}, six organs of knowledge (mask with holes)\\
Present \hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 6. \textit{sparśa}, contact (arrow entering the eye)\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 7. \textit{vedanā}, feeling (\textit{mithuna})\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| \textit{karmabhava} \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 8. \textit{tṛṣṇā}, craving (drinking man)\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| or Potential\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| side of life\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 9. \textit{upādāna}, rooted ideas (gathering flowers)\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> ~| \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 10. \textit{bhava}, action or character (pregnant woman)\\
Future \hspace{0.5cm} \> \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 11. \textit{jāti}, birth (child-birth)\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> \hspace{3cm} \> ~| 12. \textit{jarāmaraṇaśokaparidevanāduḥkhadurmanaskatā},\\
\hspace{0.5cm} \> \hspace{3cm} \> ~| decay-death-sorrow-lament-suffering-despair. 
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your preamble the same (so I haven't repeated it here), you can use a `tabular` with `\multirow` and some `\multicolumn`s to fix up the vertical lines and some extra spacing.

I have put all these in separate macros to keep the table clean. I also shifted 'Past' and 'Future' a bit dow, that way it looks nicer to me than the original.

```
\newcommand{\MR}[1]{\multirow{2}*{#1}}
\newcommand{\MRa}{%
  \multirow{6.5}={\textit{upapattibhāva} or Receptive side of life}}
\newcommand{\MRb}{\multirow{2}{*}{–}}
\newcommand{\MRc}{%
  \multirow{3}={\textit{karmabhava} or Potential side of life}}
\newcommand{\MRd}{\multirow{6}{*}{—}}

\newcommand{\NoV}{\multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{}} % No vertical line

% small vertical spaces (with and without vertical line)
\newcommand{\VSpace}{ &  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\[-8pt]}
\newcommand{\VSpaceb}{ &\NoV  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\[-8pt]}

\begin{tabular}{l r@{}| p{2.5cm} r@{}|@{\,} r@{\,} p{7.5cm}}
\MR{Past} & \NoV &  \MRa & \MRb & 1.& \textit{avidyā}, ignorance (blind camel)\\
          & \NoV &  &  &  2. & \textit{saṃskāra}, latent dispositions (pot-maker)\\
\VSpace
          &  &  & \MRd &  3. & \textit{vijñāna}, rebirth-consciousness (ape)\\
          &  &  &  &  4. & \textit{nāmarūpa}, name and form (ferryman)\\
          &  &  &  &  5.& \textit{ṣaḍāyatana}, six organs of knowledge (mask with holes)\\ 
Present   & –&  &  &  6.& \textit{sparśa}, contact (arrow entering the eye)\\  
          &  &  &  &  7.& \textit{vedanā}, feeling (\textit{mithuna})\\
\VSpace
          &  &\MRc & &  8.& \textit{tṛṣṇā}, craving (drinking man)\\
          &  &  &  &  9.& \textit{upādāna}, rooted ideas (gathering flowers)\\
          &  &  &  &  10.& \textit{bhava}, action or character (pregnant woman)\\
\VSpaceb
\MR{Future} & \NoV &  & \MRb &  11.& \textit{jāti}, birth (child-birth)\\
          & \NoV &  &  & 12.& \textit{jarāmaraṇaśokaparidevanāduḥkhadurmanaskatā},\\
          & \NoV &  & \NoV & & decay-death-sorrow-lament-suffering-despair. \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Pieter van Oostrum, thanks a lot! Its perfect!